# using an update in an insert for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an insert query that is running with a select subquery. This needs to basically "fork off" copies of the rows it finds and inserts. This part works but there is no garbage collection. I have this running on a database event so it finds records based on the criteria then forks it off as new records... runs again fork this off. Any ideas so the record it finds is maybe updated or a way to stop the cycle.

```
INSERT INTO charity (pid, itemname, newval)
SELECT cha.pid, cha.itemname, 'ref') 
FROM charity AS cha, entry AS ent
WHERE cha.pid = ent.id 
AND cha.status = 'Pending' 
AND cha.type = 'CHAR' 
AND ent.dates < CURDATE()
AND ent.total > (SELECT sum(price) FROM charity WHERE cha.type = 'CHAR')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a left join against the table for matching forked records and exclude those already forked.

```
INSERT INTO charity (pid, itemname, newval)
SELECT cha.pid, cha.itemname, 'ref') 
FROM charity AS cha, entry AS ent
left outer join charity as cha2 
   on cha2.pid=cha.pid and cha2.itemname = cha.itemname and
      cha2.newval='ref'
WHERE cha.pid = ent.id 
AND cha.status = 'Pending' 
AND cha.type = 'CHAR' 
AND ent.dates < CURDATE()
AND ent.total > (SELECT sum(price) FROM charity WHERE cha.type = 'CHAR') 
AND cha2.pid IS NULL
```

Warning - not tested. There isn't enough information for me to adequately specify the records that might already have been created.

You may also need to add further tests in the join on clause. Basically this locates record for which the associated new record has not yet been created - in this case a reford with newval='ref' where the other 2 fields match.

Comment: I tried the below, where I added NOT EXISTS... hoping that INSERT would look still insert the ref column in newval but look if for the pid 
and if that pid had a record with a newval of ref don't insert it. But it went wrong


INSERT INTO charity (pid, itemname, newval)
SELECT cha.pid, cha.itemname, 'ref') 
FROM charity AS cha, entry AS ent 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT newval FROM charity WHERE newval = 'ref')
AND cha.pid = ent.id 
AND cha.status = 'Pending' 
AND cha.type = 'CHAR' 
AND ent.dates < CURDATE()
AND ent.total > (SELECT sum(price) FROM charity WHERE cha.newval = 'CHAR')

Comment: I dont think your subquery is explicit enough - it will coutn ANY record where newval = 'ref' irrespective of the other fields.